# How can I mount network drives consistently in macOS?

Tags: macos, mount, network-shares

The issue is that I have a shared drive with 3 partitions on my router.

- The router insists on exporting a drive letter ("G", "H" and "I") instead of partition names.
- The FS browser ("Finder") shows the drive letters.
- The FS itself mounts them as `/Volume/router and /Volume/router-1` and `/Volume/router-2`.
- I use shell scripts to manage much of the data on (two of) these volumes.
- **MOST IMPORTANTLY** the mapping between the FS mount points and the drive letters is **INCONSISTENT**.

If there is some way to do it with the automounter, the documentation wasn't clear enough to me to figure out how. I currently use a script for all the scripts that need to know which mount point to use:

```sh
#! /bin/echo this file should be sourced, not executed

die() {
  echo "FATAL ERROR: $*"
  exit 1
} 1>&2

set -- /Volumes/router*/disk_part*:*

for f
do
  dname=${f##*:}
  tst=$(cat $f)
  test "X$dname" = "X$tst" || die "Mismatch: '$dname' v. '$tst'"
  eval ${dname}_disk=${f%/*}
done
```

```
  FS Types: both smbfs ("G" partition not mounted)
  Firmware Version: 1.1.9 Build 20231115 rel.37295(5553)
  Hardware Version: Archer AXE75 v1.0
```

[image: Automount from "map auto_home"]

Comment: Could you edit your Question to include which remote filesystem protocol you're using? I'm guessing some version of SMB, but it would be great if it was in the text of the post. It would also be helpful to know the make and model of your router and what firmware you're running on it, so if this is, say, something Linux-based like OpenWrt running SaMBa, we could give you tips on adjusting the smb.conf on the router if needed. If you're using SMB, have you looked at the macOS man page for `mount_smbfs(8)` to see if that gives you the options you need to control the things you want to control?

Comment: TY. Doing it now.

Comment: P.S. "man page for mount_smbfs(8) to see if that gives you the options you need"

It does. In particular, the last argument is a mount point. Unless I rig something up to do the mount (bypassing automount), there's no way to specify that. numb.conf allows a lot of parameters, but not a mount point. That conf file is new to me, it just doesn't help for this problem. Thank you.